# How do you make a nested select with a restriction (WHERE)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database for a small calendar app in which people are stored in the clients table, dates are stored in the table calendarDate and since the relations are many to many there is a connecting table called client_date which holds both of their ids.

I want to make a nested select to get all the dates for a particular person lets say with id = 2.
I came up with this, but it prints all of the dates and asigns them to the person with that id, instead of just printing the only ones he is asigned to:

```
SELECT c.username
     , c.country
     , d.day
     , d.month
     , d.year
     , d.dayOfWeek
     , d.weekOfYear
     , d.emotionId
     , d.id 
  from clients as c 
  join calendarDate as d 
    on d.id in (SELECT dateId 
                  from client_date 
                 WHERE clientId in (SELECT id 
                                      from clients )
               ) 
 where c.id = 2;
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or is there another way to make a nested select statement ?

My database and data:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS calendar;
CREATE DATABASE calendar;
USE calendar;

CREATE TABLE clients(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
joinedOnDate DATE NOT NULL,
country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE emotions(
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
value DOUBLE 
);

CREATE TABLE calendarDate(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
day INT NOT NULL,
month INT NOT NULL,
year INT NOT NULL,
dayOfWeek VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
weekOfYear int NOT NULL,
emotionId INT NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (emotionId)
    REFERENCES emotions( id )
);

CREATE TABLE client_date(
dateId INT NOT NULL,
clientId INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY ( dateId )
    REFERENCES calendarDate( id ) ,
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY ( clientId )
    REFERENCES clients( id ) ,
UNIQUE KEY( dateId, clientId )  
);

USE calendar;

INSERT INTO emotions (id, name, value) VALUES
(0, 'None', 1),
(1, 'Excited', 2.0),
(2, 'Happy', 2.0),
(3, 'Positive', 1.5),
(4, 'Average', 1.0),
(5, 'Mixed', 1),
(6, 'Negative', 0.5),
(7, 'Sad', 0);

INSERT INTO clients (username, joinedOnDate, country) VALUES
('Malazzar', DATE(NOW()), 'Bulgaria'),
('Preslava981', DATE(NOW()), 'Bulgaria'),
('Thusnake', DATE(NOW()), 'United Kingdom');

INSERT INTO calendarDate (day, month, year, dayOfWeek, weekOfYear, emotionId) VALUES
(1, 1, 2019, 'Tuesday', 1, 0),
(2, 1, 2019, 'Wednesday', 1, 0),
(3, 1, 2019, 'Thursday', 1, 0),
(4, 1, 2019, 'Friday', 1, 0),
(5, 1, 2019, 'Saturday', 1, 0),
(6, 1, 2019, 'Sunday', 1, 0),
(7, 1, 2019, 'Monday', 2, 0),
(8, 1, 2019, 'Tuesday', 2, 0),
(9, 1, 2019, 'Wednesday', 2, 0),
(10, 1, 2019, 'Thursday', 2, 0),
(11, 1, 2019, 'Friday', 2, 0),
(12, 1, 2019, 'Saturday', 2, 0),
(13, 1, 2019, 'Sunday', 2, 0),
(14, 1, 2019, 'Monday', 3, 0);

INSERT INTO client_date (clientId, dateId) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 4),
(1, 5),
(1, 6),
(1, 7),
(2, 8),
(2, 9),
(2, 10),
(2, 11),
(2, 12),
(2, 13),
(2, 14);
```

The output I get for the particular client:

```
Preslava981 Bulgaria    1   1   2019    Tuesday     1   0   1
Preslava981 Bulgaria    2   1   2019    Wednesday   1   0   2
Preslava981 Bulgaria    3   1   2019    Thursday    1   0   3
Preslava981 Bulgaria    4   1   2019    Friday      1   0   4
Preslava981 Bulgaria    5   1   2019    Saturday    1   0   5
Preslava981 Bulgaria    6   1   2019    Sunday      1   0   6
Preslava981 Bulgaria    7   1   2019    Monday      2   0   7
Preslava981 Bulgaria    8   1   2019    Tuesday     2   0   8
Preslava981 Bulgaria    9   1   2019    Wednesday   2   0   9
Preslava981 Bulgaria    10  1   2019    Thursday    2   0   10
Preslava981 Bulgaria    11  1   2019    Friday      2   0   11
Preslava981 Bulgaria    12  1   2019    Saturday    2   0   12
Preslava981 Bulgaria    13  1   2019    Sunday      2   0   13
Preslava981 Bulgaria    14  1   2019    Monday      3   0   14
```

Comment: I don't see any need for any nested statements here. Joins will do the job perfectly well. Note that a desired result is always useful.

Comment: Yes I know, I have already done it with a double JOIN, but I was told that it was better and faster to use nested SELECT statements. Also I want to understand how they work better.

Comment: You were misinformed.

Comment: What if instead of using this `WHERE clientId in (SELECT id 
                                      from clients )` try this `WHERE clientId = c.id`. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
WHERE clientId in (SELECT id from clients)
```

*Every* client ID exists in the clients table. You want this instead:

```
WHERE clientId = c.id
```

You could also use a non-corelated subquery instead, which is easier to read:

```
on (c.id, d.id) in (select clientid, dateid from client_date)
```

But as has been mentioned by others, a mere join to `client_date` would do the same job.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `join`s?

```
select c.username, c.country, d.*
from clients c  join
     client_date cd
     on cd.clientId = c.id join
     calendarDate as d 
     on d.id cd.dateId 
 where c.id = 2;
```

Comment: Yes, this indeed works and I have already made it using two joins, but I wanted to do it with just one and nested SELECTs because my professor told me they would be faster and knowing them would be beneficial.

Comment: @Malazzar . . . Knowing them is no doubt beneficial.  However, it is doubtful that subqueries would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a nested select to get all the dates for a particular
>   person lets say with id = 2

This can be done with:

```
select *
from calendarDate
where day in (
  select dateId
  from client_date
  where clientId = 2
)
```

An equivalent JOIN query would be:

```
select d.*
from calendarDate d
join client_date cd
  on cd.dateId = d.day
where cd.clientId = 2
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eVUdtqRZiV4hjvEm6tuV6N/0)

Note: The two queries are only equivalent, if there are no duplicates in the `client_date` table.

If you want to select data from more than one table, then you actualy **need** to use a JOIN. In that case asking for how to do it without joins, wouldn't make sense.